# Reading tab (\t) separated text from file in shell

Tags: bash, shell, text-files

my text file looks like this

```
1   get a   06-05-2000
2   get b   06-05-2001
3   get c   06-05-2002
4   get d   06-05-1442
5   get e   06-05-1998
6   get f   06-05-1909
```

I want to read what is after the first `\t` (tab) and store that in `varA` and what is after `\t` (the other tab) and store that in `varB`

using SHELL

Comment: 1 get a 06-05-1991 (enter)
2 get b 06-05-1991 (enter)
3 get c  06-05-1991 (enter)
4 get d 06-05-1991 (enter)       each is on one line, and between the first number and the text and the date i have tabs

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bash you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a varA varB
while IFS=$'\t' read -r num first second;do
varA+=("$first")
varB+=("$second")
done <file
echo ${varA[1]} ${varB[1]}
```

You can access each element of `varA` array using index `${varA[$index]}` or all of them at once with `${varA[@]}`.